# Django 2.1 ProgrammingError at /admin column + _id does not exist

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

While trying to run my second **Django 2.1 /Postgres 10** project I got stuck with the following programming error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/vocs_app/subsubscriber/

column sub_subscriber.sub_prev_sst_uid_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...", "sub_subscriber"."sub_next_recharge_datetime", "sub_subsc...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "sub_subscriber.sub_prev_sst_uid".
```

I can open the `admin app` of my application, i.e., `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/vocs_app`.
It lists all imported models from my database; to illustrate my case I believe the following classes are sufficient:

(taken from `my_site/vocs_app/models.py`:)

```
from django.db import models

class VneVirtualNetwork(models.Model):
    vne_uid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    vne_nop_uid = models.ForeignKey(NopNetworkOperator, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='vne_nop_uid')
    vne_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vne_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vne_external_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    vne_idd_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    vne_sn_length = models.IntegerField()
    createdon = models.DateTimeField()
    createdby = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    createdfrom = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    modifiedon = models.DateTimeField()
    modifiedby = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    modifiedfrom = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'vne_virtual_network'

class SstSystemStatus(models.Model):
    sst_uid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    sst_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sst_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    startdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    enddate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sst_system_status'

class SubSubscriber(models.Model):
    sub_uid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    sub_vne_uid = models.ForeignKey('VneVirtualNetwork', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sub_vne_uid')
    sub_rpl_uid = models.ForeignKey(RplRatePlan, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sub_rpl_uid')
    sub_account_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_external_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_hzn_uid = models.ForeignKey(HznHomezoneName, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sub_hzn_uid')
    sub_low_balance_trigger = models.BooleanField()
    sub_first_call_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sub_last_enabled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sub_last_disabled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sub_last_recharge_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sub_next_recharge_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    sub_prev_sst_uid = models.ForeignKey(SstSystemStatus, related_name='sub_prev_sst_uid',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    sub_sst_uid = models.ForeignKey(SstSystemStatus, related_name='sub_sst_uid',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    startdatetime = models.DateTimeField()
    enddatetime = models.DateTimeField()
    createdon = models.DateTimeField()
    createdby = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    createdfrom = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    modifiedon = models.DateTimeField()
    modifiedby = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    modifiedfrom = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sub_subscriber'
```

`class SubSubscriber` references **foreign key** `sst_uid` of **table/class** `SstSystemStatus` twice (previous and current status). It seems Django doesn't like it. Other tables such as `VneVirtualNetwork` (which contain a "single" foreign key references) don't cause any issue. The admin GUI allows me to display and change their data.

The fault message shows that Django tries to complement the name of field `sub_prev_sst_uid` with `'_id'`. If I comment the relevant line in file **model.py** and try to display the subscriber table it will cause the same error, this time with field `sub_sst_uid`. How can I prevent Django from appending `'_id'`?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Django will use the related name and/or the chosen class field name, add a suffix "_id" and try to locate a column of this name in the database. Unless you explicitly define the db_column as follows:

```
sub_sst_uid = models.ForeignKey('SstSystemStatus', db_column='sub_sst_uid', related_name='sub_sst_uid', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

sub_prev_sst_uid = models.ForeignKey('SstSystemStatus', db_column='sub_prev_sst_uid', related_name='sub_prev_sst_uid', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```